# How to debug Jhipster maven backend from InteliJ?

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, jhipster

I using a latest Jhipster React application. I tried debuging by running the main method. But I am getting and error like this.

`
Description:
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
javax.el.ELManager.getExpressionFactory(ELManager.java:38)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
javax.el.ExpressionFactory javax.el.ELUtil.getExpressionFactory()
```

The method's class, javax.el.ELUtil, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/D:/ENEX/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jar!/javax/el/ELUtil.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/udara/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jakarta.el/3.0.3/jakarta.el-3.0.3.jar!/javax/el/ELUtil.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/D:/ENEX/lib/javax.servlet.jsp.jar
```

Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of javax.el.ELUtil
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55057', transport: 'socket'
Process finished with exit code 0
`

Any idea how to debug the jhsipter application backend.

Comment: What is the jar file not coming from your maven repository data? Did you change something or have a special intelliJ config that takes the jar file under `ENEX/lib` into account?

Comment: It's the same as debugging any spring boot application launched by maven. Anyway, you probably don't need a debugger to fix a classpath issue: inspect `mwnw dependency:tree` and exclude one of the 2 jars.